# Convert QAudioBuffer to QByteArray : loss of information?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qbytearray

I have a WAV file that I decode with the QAudioDecoder. As a result I have a QAudioBuffer object. I want to store the data stored in QAudioBuffer in a QByteArray for my QIODevice derived class. I want to use this data in the ReadData method of my derived class for audio output. I now have 2 questions:

- How to get a QByteArray from a QAuddioBuffer?
  I used the following code, but unfortunately this is not correct. The data in QAudioBuffer is coded to 2Bytes, but each element in a QByteArray is coded to 1Byte (right?). Don't we have a loss of information there? To test if QByteArray contains the original data from the WAV file, I save it to a TXT file.
- is this approach appropriate? I actually want to apply some operations on the data stored in QAudioBuffer (e.g. filters) and listen to the result in real time.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
QAudioFormat *format_decoder;
format_decoder = new QAudioFormat;
format_decoder->setSampleRate(44100);
format_decoder->setChannelCount(1);
format_decoder->setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int16);

QAudioDecoder decoder;
decoder.setSource(filenameSource);
decoder.setAudioFormat(*format_decoder);
decoder.start();

QObject::connect(&decoder, &QAudioDecoder::bufferReady, this, &MainWindow::slot_bufReady);
```

and the slot

```
void MainWindow::slot_bufReady(){

QAudioBuffer buffer = m_audioDecoder->read();
QByteArray buffer_ByteArray(buffer.constData<char>(), buffer.byteCount());

QFile file(filenameTest1);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append)) {
        qDebug() << "ERRO ";  }

QTextStream strem(&file);
for(auto const dat: buffer_ByteArray)  {
        strem<< qreal(dat)/128.0<< "\r\n";
    }
file.cloe();
```

Comment: As already told you on another forum - since audio data is binary data you **must not** wirte it out as text but treat it as binary data and write it out with [QFile::write(QByteArray)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#write-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

```
for(auto const dat: buffer_ByteArray)  {
        strem<< qreal(dat)/128.0<< "\r\n";
    }
```

Your audio format is 16-bit mono. Reading it byte by byte is a non-starter.  Read it sample by sample. That is, read two bytes at a time and convert.  More likely this:

```
int16_t* data = (int16_t*)(buffer.data());
int samples = buffer.sampleCount();
for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
{
    strem << data[i] << "\r\n";
}
```

The above will save your samples into a text file. You could plot it with Excel. But as others have said, that's not as useful as saving in as binary. You could prepend a WAV file header such that it can be played and analyzed with other tools.

**Update**

If your intent is to transcode from 16-bit to 8-bit, this is how you would likely do it:

```
 int16_t* data = (int16_t*)(buffer.data());
 QByteArray buffer_ByteArray(buffer.sampleCount(), '\0');
 for (size_t i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
     buffer_ByteArray[i] = (char)(data[i] / 256); // 16-bit to 8-bit
 }
```

Note: some audio platforms use unsigned integers for 8-bit audio. That is the zero amplitude sample is 0x80.  This is the case for 8-bit WAV files.  If that's in play, then change this line:

```
buffer_ByteArray[i] = (char)(data[i] / 256); // 16-bit to 8-bit
```

To this:

```
char c = (char)(data[i] / 256); // 16-bit to 8-bit signed
const unsigned char mask = 0x80;
buffer_ByteArray[i] = (char)(mask ^ c);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your Intervation.
this is right, but my problem is to convert a 16bit sample QAudioBuffer to a QByteArray. I would even like to know if it is possible, since for my QAudioBuffer my elements are coded on 16 bits and for a QByteArray each element is coded on 8 bits

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how to convert from 16-bits to 8-bit audio samples.

Comment: Hello,
thank you very much for your answer. This is what I needed. I tried it and it works.
However, I think that with the conversion we lose some precision of the signal. You can feel it when you listen to it, there are low intensity noises. 
Thanks again for the help. I have a question. Why divide by 256?

Comment: *I think that with the conversion we lose some precision of the signal.* - Exactly what did you think would happen when converting a 16-bit recording to 8-bit? :)  The SNR drops from like 96db to 48db.  But if you want to share a recording, I might be able to tell you if there's something obvious...